# Ubuntu 14 can detect wifi but cannot connect to internet

Tags: networking

I just had my ubuntu 14 installed, but `every now and then` it fails to connect to internet, even though it showed that it's connected to wifi. Anyone knows how to fix this?

to be specific, it will not work for sure after get back on from "suspend" , only after reboot the system, it will get back to work. restart the network manager will not do the work.

```
[  124.766933] rtl8723be 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  124.766935] rtl8723be 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  124.768786] wlan0: associate with 1c:af:f7:bf:7b:74 (try 1/3)
[  124.770896] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 1c:af:f7:bf:7b:74 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[  124.771015] wlan0: associated
[  124.771026] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[  124.804933] wlan0: deauthenticating from 1c:af:f7:bf:7b:74 by local choice (reason=2)
[  124.839042] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[  124.839612] wlan0: authenticate with 1c:af:f7:bf:7b:74
[  124.849728] wlan0: send auth to 1c:af:f7:bf:7b:74 (try 1/3)
[  124.849825] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[  124.849827] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[  124.849829] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  124.849830] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  124.849831] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  124.849832] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  124.849833] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[  124.855366] wlan0: authenticated
[  124.855584] rtl8723be 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT/VHT due to WEP/TKIP use
[  124.855591] rtl8723be 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling HT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  124.855594] rtl8723be 0000:02:00.0 wlan0: disabling VHT as WMM/QoS is not supported by the AP
[  124.856860] wlan0: associate with 1c:af:f7:bf:7b:74 (try 1/3)
[  124.860693] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 1c:af:f7:bf:7b:74 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=6)
[  124.860852] wlan0: associated
```

Comment: Can you post the logs from `dmesg` ?

Comment: @shaddy I have updated the post

Comment: to be specific, it will not work for sure after get back on from "suspend"

Answer (score 1):

After you mentioned this occurs only after coming back from suspend, the following solution seems to work:

```sh
sudo touch /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
sudo chmod +x /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
sudo gedit /etc/pm/sleep.d/wakenet.sh
```

Insert the following lines:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
case "$1" in
  thaw|resume)
    nmcli nm sleep false
    pkill -f wpa_supplicant
    ;;
  *)
    ;;
esac
exit $?
```

Source: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218043